# Table with dynamic CSS class hidden via jQuery call in other file

Tags: jquery, css

I have several tables which are generated in a foreach in reader.php

```
<table class="object_list_<?php echo $title; ?>">
```

In the same file there are links with a jquery-call:

```
<a href="#" onclick="show_object('<?php echo $itemId.','.$title; ?>')"><?php echo (string)$flat.'</a><br />'; ?>
```

My jQuery function in the handler file catalogue.php looks like this:

```
<script>
    function show_object(itemid,object_type){
        var request = $.ajax({
            url: "show_object.php",
            type: "GET",
            data: "id="+ itemid,
            dataType: "html"
        });
        $(table['.object_list_' + object_type]).hide();
        request.done(function(msg) {
            $(".show_object").append(msg);          
        });
        request.fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus) {
            alert( "Request failed: " + textStatus );
        });
    }       
</script>
```

The problem is with the hide() function

```
$(table['.object_list_' + object_type]).hide();
```

This does not work. Please note that the `object_type` is the same as `$title` in the other file, I am passing it through the a href javascript call.

I have been searching here at stackoverflow and google, but I just cannot find the error. It loads correctly the show_object.php, but does not hide the table.

I have tried several other versions too, like:

```
$('.object_list_' + object_type).hide();
```

and adding the data first in variable and then in the hide function.. none works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you all who tried to help! I was one litte stupid mistake I did.

I have to divert the variables passed through javascript with ' marks.

```
<a href="#" onclick="show_object('<?php echo $itemId."','".$title; ?>')"><?php echo (string)$flat.'</a><br />'; ?>
```

The output has to be like this:

```
<a href="#" onclick="show_object('2013084','Kerrostalot')">4h,k,sauna,terassi</a>
```

The javascript call assumed they are one variable, not two..

I feel so stupid...

Answer (score 0):

```
$(table['.object_list_' + object_type]).hide();
```

is not correct, you have to use your second statement :

```
$('.object_list_' + object_type).hide();
```

or even better

```
$('table.object_list_' + object_type).hide();
```

Try to alert 'object_type' juste before "hide" call and try to execute it manually via firebug/chrome console, I think you've an error.

What happened ?

Comment: Thank you! Strange, I did alert it `alert(object_type);` but I got an "undefinied" alert box. Why is this? The source code with the a href is correct `<a href="#" onclick="show_object('2001220,Kerrostalot')">3h,k,sauna,psh,wc,parveke</a>` .. why is the variable undefinied?

Comment: Another strange thing, the script calls the ajax with the second variable from the function, I checked with the javascript console of chrome. I see the following request: `show_object.php?id=1885880,Kerrostalot` But I do not add the second variable to the ajax call, as you can see above?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to hook it in using a class on the table instead of an inline onclick?

You can use jQuery to pull any information you need from the table. This is a rough outline, hopefully this helps? In this case I'd put the id of the thing you want in a data-id="" attribute on the a, saves messing about.

```
$('table.class a').click(function(e){

    /* Stop normal a click action by preventing default */
    e.preventDefault();

    /* Get the item id and define a $this to use later */
    var itemId = $(this).attr('data-id'), $this = $(this);

    /* Use nicer $.get syntax, pass the id */
    $.get('show_object.php',{
        id:itemId
    },function(data){

        /* Put your data in the target */
        $('target').append(data);

        /* Use the $this item to hide the a you clicked on */
        $this.hide();
    }
});
```

Hope that helps, I can try something more specific if necessary?

Comment: Thank you Mark, but what I cannot use the click in the table. The table is a list of catalog-objects from an xml-file. The a link is one object of the list. When its clicked, I have to hide the table list and load detail info from the object.

Comment: I see. No problem. I was trying to tag onto the a within the table kind of how you have done it. I think we may need a little more of the structure of your code to help a bit more.

Comment: Thank you very much! As you can see in the second answer, for some reason the object_type is undefinied, and added to the get variables, altough I am not doing it by myself? Maybe there below is more info you need?